# Is the inducing signal weakened to the extent it induces a signal in the receiving antenna?

Tags: radio, antennas

Silly question ...
An antenna is necessary to receive a transmitted signal from atmosphere, or otherwise. The transmitted signal weakens as it travels through the atmosphere. When the signal encounters an antenna (subject to antenna gain) a corresponding signal is induced in the antenna.

Is the inducing signal weakened to the extent it induces a signal in the receiving antenna?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so, but I can't give you any authoritative information.  I am working on a similar problem with ferrite rod antennas and experimentally I've confirmed that the induced current in the antenna also re-radiates.

Current in an antenna has no idea how it "got there". Current flowing in a conductor will create a magnetic field around that conductor.  I am seeking confirmation that this field opposes the incoming signal.

If we had a perfect lossless resonant antenna, the signal would induce a current which would slosh back and forth in the antenna. Subsequent carrier cycles would add more current. Without some limiting mechanism, the current could become infinite over a long time..  Obviously that doesn't happen.  Resistive losses, other parasitic losses, and re-radiated energy combine to achieve an equilibrium.  This takes time, which ends up expressing as the "Q" of the antenna.  Our imaginary perfect antenna would have infinite Q. Real antennas don't.